# Android onActivityResult intent parameter is null periodically

Tags: android

I have a "saved game chooser" activity for users to open saved games. I start the activity for result and return a string that represents the saved game to the parent activity.

The code I've been using is no more complex than this:

```
if(savedGameId != null) {
    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra("saved_game_key", savedGameId); 
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
    finish();
}
```

In onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
    case SAVED_GAME_ACTIVITY:
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(data.hasExtra("saved_game_key") {
                String savedGameId = data.getExtra("saved_game_key");
                ...
            } else {
                // couldn't load game
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This has worked for me on all my test devices and emulators 100% of the time. However, I periodically get a crash report for a NPE for the `data.hasExtra("saved_game_key")` call.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.hasExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.xxxx.yyyy.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6508)
    ...
```

The android versions and devices I've received this report so far:

- Android 6.0 - MI MAX (hydrogen)
- Android 6.0 - Lenovo K5 Note (A7020a48)
- Android 6.0 - Moto G(4) (athene)
- Android 5.1 - Galaxy Note 10.1 (lt033g)
- Android 4.0.3 - 4.0.4 - Xperia tipo dual (ST21a2)

I have not been able to reproduce this issue myself. I'm going to try to get ahold of one of the above devices and see if I can get any more info.

In the meantime, I've searched google/stackoverflow and have not found anything that resembles this specific situation.

**My Question**

Is there something, some edge case that I've overlooked that could cause the returned data intent to be null in certain situations?

Like I said, I've never been able to reproduce this issue myself and the code looks correct based on other examples that I've seen for returning data from intents. If you need more information please leave me a comment.

Comment: Your stack trace does not line up with your code. Your code is calling `getExtra()`; your stack trace is complaining about `hasExtra()`. Assuming that you always provide a non-`null` `Intent` to `setResult()`, and that you are only looking for extras in the `RESULT_OK` branch, you should be fine AFAIK. Make sure that your saved-game-chooser activity only ever has the one `setResult()` call, and that there's no code path down which you might accidentally be calling `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)` with no `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare my code is calling `data.hasExtra()` in the conditional just before calling `data.getExtra()`.

Comment: Damn, I'm having difficulty reading SO code today... My apologies. The rest of my comment still stands, though: try to confirm that there is no scenario in which you are sending `RESULT_OK` but not including an `Intent`. The default "result" is `RESULT_CANCELED`, and so any other exit path from your saved-game-chooser activity (e.g., user presses BACK) should not result in `RESULT_OK`.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's fine. :-) Yeah, this code really is as simple as what I've shown here. I've never actually been able to reproduce this error myself. Nevertheless, I've got 11 error reports in my Developer Console showing this crash. I was hoping there is some edge case that I just don't know about. I'm at a loss at the moment as to where to even start. How do you fix correct code? :-)

Comment: If this is a once-in-a-blue-moon crash (i.e., handful of devices, and even they only get it on rare occasion), you might settle for checking for `null` and doing an "oops, something went wrong, please try again" UI. Beyond that, depending on what you are getting from your crash reports, see if there are signs that your process is really new. A common source of edge cases is your process being terminated in the background (e.g., user went into saved-game-chooser, pressed HOME, returned 20 minutes later), though I can't see how that could cause problems in your specific situation.

Comment: @CommonsWare it does seem to be fairly rare though from the reports I have there seems to be multiple reports per device. That tells me some devices may be more susceptible than others. I already threw in the null check so that will go out with my next update. I'd rather fix the cause than the symptom so I'll try to get one of the above devices on ebay and keep digging.